# Numpy nanargmin and nanargmax don't work with datetime-arrays

Tags: python, numpy

The functions `np.nanmin`, `np.nanmin`, `np.nanargmin` and `np.nanargmax` are supposed to ignore Nan-values, but behave unexpected with `datetime64[s]`-arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['NaT','2020-01-30'],dtype='datetime64[s]')

#this works as expected
print('nanmin:', np.nanmin(a)) # =2020-01-30T00:00:00
print('nanmax:', np.nanmax(a)) # =2020-01-30T00:00:00

#this does not
print('nanargmin:', np.nanargmin(a)) #should be 1, is 0
print('nanargmax:', np.nanargmax(a)) #should be 1, is 0
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something here? I am using numpy 1.19.1.

Comment: Are you sure you can use NaN functions to deal with NaTs?

Comment: `nan` is a `float`.  The `nan...` functions are designed to deal with float dtype arrays.  I believe `NaT` is a relatively recent addition, and I don't see evidence in the `nanmin` or `nanargmin` code of them being adapted to work with that.

Comment: `nanmin` notes that: "If the input has a integer type the function is equivalent to np.min."  `datetime64[s]` is actually an `int64` interpreted as a datetime.

Comment: @hpaulj interesting to note that ``NaT``, even as ``int``, has some weird behaviour: ``np.datetime64('nat').astype(int)=0``, but ``np.datetime64('nat').astype(float)=-9.223372036854776e+18``.

Comment: I get a large negative number for the `NaT` int conversion.  But in any case `datatime64` implements its own value comparisons, so we shouldn't expect it to behave like either int or float.